# htaccess lose parameter but keep variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

In about a week we have to go live with a website on a new domain. But we don't want everyone to get 404's so we want to redirect everyone.

Our problem is as followed,

old link: `http://www.example.com/one/detail?id=12345-54321-21345-32145-43215`
new link: `http://www.newpage.com/one/12345-54321-21345-32145-43215/`

So what we want is just the '12345-54321-21345-32145-43215', without 'detail?='

We have tried a lot of things but for some reason we can not lose the 'detail?='

I have been trying it locally,

newpage has the following htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The example page has been changed so many times trying to figure out what that it would be useless to post it..

EDIT: Both sites on live are wordpress websites
EDIT2: Detail?= changed into Detail?id= because I formulated it wrong.

The answer worked for what was previously the question. I tried changing it to

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:id)?=([0-9-]+)$
RewriteRule ^one/detail/id$ http://newdomain.com/one/%1/? [NC,L,R=301]
```

But that doesn't work. How can I fix this? (or should I just have created a new question for this?)

Comment: your rewrites aren't doing a client-side redirect - it's purely an internal server-side-only rewrite. you need to an `[R=301]` so the client's in-address-bar url gets changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your htaccess, add:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:detail)?=([0-9-]+)$
RewriteRule ^one/detail$ http://newdomain.com/one/%1/? [NC,L,R=301]
```

This will redirect `/one/detail?=12345-54321-21345-32145-43215` to `/one/12345-54321-21345-32145-43215/` with a `HTTP 301 code` (moved permanently).

**UPDATE**: to redirect `default?id=` instead of `default?=` you can just include `id` within the expression:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:detail)?id=([0-9-]+)$
RewriteRule ^one/detail$ http://newdomain.com/one/%1/? [NC,L,R=301]
```

This will redirect `/one/detail?id=12345-54321-21345-32145-43215` to `/one/12345-54321-21345-32145-43215/` with a `HTTP 301 code` (moved permanently).

Comment: Hey there, while your answer completely worked for me, the live site was a little different(completely my fault). I have edited the question and hope you could give some insight/an answer to that as well.

Comment: Answer updated to include an example for `detail?id=` instead of `detail?=`. You want the `id` outside of the first expression (pair of parentheses).